# Conflict about required and valuechangeListener for <p:selectonemenu>

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="roleId" value="#{accessPage.roleId}" required="true">                   
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['label.common.selecthere']}" itemValue="#{null}" />          
   <f:selectItems var="code" value="#{accessPage.roleIdList}" itemLabel="#{code.codeDesc}" itemValue="#{code.codeId}" />    
   <f:valueChangeListener type="com.ncs.caseconnect.base.app.utils.ValueChangeCleanUtils"/>    
   <p:ajax listener="#{accessPage.roleOrModuleChanged}" update="accessRight" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

the valueChangeListener and ajax not work when we select the first null option. If we remove the required attribute it works fine. Is it conflict between required and valueChangeListener?

Answer (score 0):

try to replace

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['label.common.selecthere']}" itemValue="#{null}" />
```

with

```
<f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="#{msg['label.common.selecthere']}"/>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel: When I tried you solution, the first null option can not be selected anywhere.

Comment: why do you want to select null? I suggested you to add an option that cannot be selected...

Comment: I means that when I open the page, the first null option should be selected as default. But now the second one is selected.

Comment: why don you define your `roleId` as `String roleId = "defaultValue"` and in postconstractor simply override it if needed... ?

Comment: The roleId is String and roleIdList is List<String>

Comment: so in your post constructor do `roleId = roleIdList.get(0)` (check for null/isemprty ofcourse)